# How can I create this function for styling a string from a database?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

Say I have a string with some custom code for example:

```
const text = "*(i) this is italics *(/i) this is not *(b) but this is in bold *(/b)";
```

How can I make a function that automatically converts this text into:

*this is italics* this is not **but this is in bold**

Im using react but of course normal Javascript can be used to. Im probably being stupid but eventually I want to create a database with lots of these texts in which I can put into this function and it will automatically format.

Thanks

Comment: Your styling kind of looks like BBCode. If you change `()` to `[]`, you could use a BBCode parser like [this](https://github.com/JimLiu/bbcode-to-react). Or if your users are more familiar with it, just go with Markdown since there's a bunch of support for it in libraries like [this](https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure how you plan to use it, but here's a test in codesandbox:

```
const setToBold = (str) => {
  return <b>{str}</b>;
};

const setToItal = (str) => {
  return <i>{str}</i>;
};

const combine = (boldText, italicsText) => {
  const bold = setToBold(boldText);
  const ital = setToItal(italicsText);
  return (
    <span>
      {bold} {ital}
    </span>
  );
};
```

You can try it out here: [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-hawking-ei02t?file=/src/App.js:51-344)